# Image and words with classes won't display (PHP CSS HTML)

Tags: php, html, css

Got problem displaying the below picture and words, what am I doing wrong?

```
echo "<img src="images/<?php echo $row["image"]; ?>" class="img-responsive" /><br />";
echo "<h4 class="text-info"><?php echo $row["name"]; ?></h4>";
```

Comment: Please elaborate **"problem"**

Comment: Properly use `'` and `"`, especially in the second `echo`, plus concatenation

Comment: I also noticed that you are the `<?php?>` inside the `echo`

Comment: You should read these links: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php and http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AS you are working in php so you have no need to **echo** `<?php echo $row["image"]; ?>` in side an echo and you have to consider about **single quotes** and **double quotes**
Do like this

```
echo "<img src='images/".$row["image"]."' class='img-responsive' /><br />";
echo "<h4 class='text-info'>".$row["name"]."</h4>";
```

Comment: A good answer also contains _why_ the OP should try it. What have you changed? How does it solve the issue?

Answer (score -1):

try this.

```
echo "<img src='images/'". $row['image']." class='img-responsive' /><br />";
echo "<h4 class='text-info'>".$row['name']."</h4>";
```

Comment: redundant `echo`

Comment: A good answer also contains _why_ the OP should try it. What have you changed? How does it solve the issue?

Comment: `src='images/'". $row['image']."`... that's not correct

Answer (score -1):

At first you need to use php tag for translating echo tag  after do like this..

```
    <?php
echo '<img src="images/echo $row["image"];" class="img-responsive" /><br/>'; 
echo '<h4 class="text-info"> echo $row["name"]; </h4>';
?>
```